# why is google universal analytics not working in my webapp?

Tags: google-analytics, phonegap-build

I'm using GA in my webapp without a plugin. I'm just adding the analytics.js and changing a few bits i think are required for it to work inside a webapp (no cookies, file:// urls, etc). I'm following the technique described here http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2013/07/ga-universal-analytics-phonegap-mobile-apps - it seems to be in line with the analytics documentation.

I have a web emulator of the app too, where i dont do these changes. In the web emulator, I can see requests going out where I call them. In the app, nothing happens - no errors, no requests.

```
// google analytics
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
        ga('create', this.settings.gatrackerid, 'auto');


        if (!this.settings.emulate) {

            // the app version
            ga('set', {
                'appName'       : this.settings.appname,
                'appId'         : this.settings.appid,
                'appVersion'    : this.settings.version,
                'checkProtocolTask' : null,    // allow file://urls
                'storage'       : 'none',      // no cookies available
                'clientId'      : device.uuid  // well use phonegaps uuid
            });
        } else {

            // the web version
            ga('set', {
                'appName'       : this.settings.appname,
                'appId'         : 'emulate '+this.settings.appid,
                'appVersion'    : this.settings.version
            });
        }

        ga('send', 'screenview',{
             'screenName'   : 'foo' // works on web, not in app
        });
```

Anybody any idea on whats going wrong and how to debug it ?

Comment: Why aren't you using the plugin? I use it for 4 different PhoneGap Build apps. It's easy to use and works fine.

Comment: Everywhere where  I read about the plugin, they say `You get a pile of things you don't need but that doesn't matter.` Well, I'd rather not, thanks ... this should work just fine.

Comment: besides, a plugin wouldnt work on the emulator, which is a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading the blastam post wrong. The storage and client id are supposed to replace the third parameter of the create statement, the cookie info. The code to create a tracker is

```
ga('create', trackerid, cookieinfo)
```

In my code, cookieinfo was set to 'auto'. Works on the web, not in the app. The right code is

```
if (!this.settings.emulate) {
    ga('create', this.settings.gatrackerid, {
        'storage'       : 'none',
        'clientId'      : device.uuid
    });
    ga('set', {
        'appName'       : this.settings.appname,
        'appId'         : this.settings.appid,
        'appVersion'    : this.settings.version,
        'checkProtocolTask' : null
    });
} else {
    ga('create', this.settings.gatrackerid, 'auto');
    ga('set', {
        'appName'       : this.settings.appname,
        'appId'         : 'emulate '+this.settings.appid,
        'appVersion'    : this.settings.version
    });
}
```

and that works just great, no plugins required.